# Email: Protect spoofing from other users on same domain?

Tags: email, dkim, spf

SPF and DKIM help to validate that an email was sent from the domain it claims to have been sent from. But what if a coworker spoofs another mailbox on the same domain, i.e. spoofing an email as coming from **ceo@company.com** and sending it through the corporate mail server (so it should pass SPF and DKIM)?

Comment: Mostly you need really good spam filters for this that can decipher and reject the spam content. Sometime domain or address filters can work but mostly not.

Comment: @john that's not really an answer to the question. Spam filtering does not help with spoofing where the email is not spam.

Comment: Works for me. Zero spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPF actually authenticates the **domain** used in the bounce address a.k.a. `Return-Path`. It doesn't authenticate the domain in the `FROM` header which is typically shown to recipients by their email client software as the author of the email.

Similarly, DKIM (**Domain**keys identified mail) signatures authenticate the domain listed in the `d=` tag in the signature, not necessarily the same as the domain used in the `FROM` header.

You'll need DMARC (**Domain-based** Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance) to enforce alignment between the authenticated domain and the domain used in the `FROM` field.

All three Internet standards are designed to authenticate emails sent from authorised sources, in order to protect a **domain** from being spoofed.

If you need to protect individual senders from being spoofed, you may have a look at [digital IDs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/secure-messages-by-using-a-digital-signature-549ca2f1-a68f-4366-85fa-b3f4b5856fc6) for signing and optionally encrypting email messages from the email client of a specific user.

Please consider that email messages that are sent from other legitimate sources may not be signed with a / the same certificate, e.g. a personal christmas wish from the CEO sent by the HR / communications department from a dedicated tool such as Selligent or Salesforce or other tool. You may want to use this in your awareness training material.